# Detach and Reattach element on hash change

Tags: jquery, append, detach

I'm just learning about detach(); but am not totally clear on how to use it properly.

I'd like to detach an element with a dynamically added attribute when the document has a particular hash, and reattach (?) the element with the attribute still in place when the document has a different hash.

Seems like i'm supposed to store the element as a variable but i'm not sure how exactly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you detach with jquery you get an jquery object representing an dom element.

This could then be appended to a document or inserted before, after or inside another element.

.append()
Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

.appendTo()
Insert every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the target.

.after()
Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

.before()
Insert content, specified by the parameter, before each element in the set of matched elements.

.insertAfter()
Insert every element in the set of matched elements after the target.

.insertBefore()
Insert every element in the set of matched elements before the target.

http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Daniel but I am so green i didn't even understand some of the basics of how to deal with jquery objects . . . anyway i finally figured it out, here's a jsfiddle that might help others trying to understand detach().  (not using the hash change but figured out the basics enough to go from here)

```
$('#yellow').click(function(){
$('trees').css('background-color', 'yellow');
});

$('#detach').click(function () {
    $Trees= $('trees').detach();
});

$('#insert').click(function(){
   $($Trees).insertBefore('#yellow');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/milpool/0p27o7os/